# Horizontal scale bar in R plot

Tags: r

When I plot my fitted models in R, I get the output with a vertical scale bar. Can some one kindly tell me how to place a horizontal scale bar in R plots instead of vertical? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example, perhaps?

Comment: yeah... no indication at all what plotting system you're using and whether you're plotting data yourself or you're using the built in plot methods for the fitted object... example please

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do.

Here are some possible solutions:

> 1) If using `library(ggplot2)

add `+ coord_flip()`

> 2) If using `plot`

`plot(x = value, y = 1:length(name),...)`

Comment: The question is almost 5 years old.

Comment: yeah. intentionally cherry picked. Random fun :)